# Resolution of Image from a URL in PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the URL from which I need the resolution of the image, without downloading it in my local pc

https://static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/24C492_AS01

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to download it onto your hard disk, but without downloading it at all this is not possible. You could download it into a Python variable using the `requests` module, then get it's dimensions using `PIL`:

```py
import requests
import io
from PIL import Image

imgrequest = requests.get("https://static.grainger.com/rp/s/is/image/Grainger/24C492_AS01", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}) # the Request object
imgstring = imgrequest.content # the image as a string
imgiostream = io.BytesIO(imgstring) # PIL needs a file-like object like io.BytesIO
img = Image.open(imgiostream)
width, height = img.size
print("Width:", width, "Height:", height)
```

Output:

```py
Width: 1022 Height: 221
```